# Umbraco 8 web.config to update SMTP settings

Tags: smtp, web-config, settings, umbraco

I am using Umbraco 8 and the SMTP settings have somehow changed. I need to update them. I do not have web.config in my github repository. I've been told by customer support there is no FTP access. I managed to get access to Umbraco Cloud however I cannot update any settings from there either. Any idea on how to update the SMTP settings for Umbraco 8? Thanks!

I tried talking to customer support they asked me to get access to Umbraco Cloud and I will be able to clone the project from there including web.config however even though I have admin rights to the project I do not see the development options or the option to clone the project locally.

Comment: Umbraco Cloud is slightly different to standard Umbraco. I'm not sure if you can edit config files directly in the cloud, but you can clone the project (see here https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cloud/set-up/working-locally) and edit the smtp settings (see https://docs.umbraco.com/umbraco-cloud/set-up/smtp-settings), then push deploy the changes. Although, I feel there must be an easier way of achieving what you want....

Answer (score 1):

For Umbraco 8 and below, you need to add the mailSettings into your web.config file as shown below and described in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LPv7cR_grOg).

You can also change the notification email settings from Config>umbracoSettings.config.

For more details, please also look at [this blog post](https://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2018/08/umbraco-notifications-save-and-send-for.html) which I wrote for a v7 website.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply. I've had to get to clone the project again locally because the old clone didn't have the web.config file. I updated the SMTP settings in that file and it worked.